# inputting python from txt

Tags: python, python-3.7

i have the below values in txt. i would like to input this values to Python as an integer values.

**Text Input:**

```
Zone
4001 4002 4003 4004 4005 4006 4007 4011 4012 4014 4015 4016 4501 4502 4503 4504 4505 4507 4508 4509 4601 4602 4603 4701 4702 4703 4707 4801 4802 4803 4804 4805 4806
```

**I need this above values in python as below format- integer/float values**

```
Zone = [4001 4002 4003 4004 4005 4006 4007 4011 4012 4014 4015 4016 4501 4502 4503 4504 4505 4507 4508 4509 4601 4602 4603 4701 4702 4703 4707 4801 4802 4803 4804 4805 4806]
```

Comment: Show your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: till day, i used to enter the values directly into python code, like this ..zone=[4001,4002,4003,4004,4005,4006,4007,4011,4012,4014,4015,4016,4501,4502,4503,4504,4505,4507,4508,4509,4601,4602,4603,4701,4702,4703,4707,4801,4802,4803,4804,4805,4806]
fro=[1,3,3,4,5,7,8,8,8,9,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,16,17,17,18,18,20,22,22,24,24,24,24,24,25]
to=[6,3,1,2,1,1,4,10,12,22,8,4,9,21,16,11,21,8,20,14,13,18,16,19,17,23,30,9,23,12,5,28,7]    now i want this inputs to be directly taken from txt file or excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code :

```
>>> zones_string = 'a b c'
>>> zones_list = zones_string.split(' ')
>>> zones_list
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

Comment: thanks for your input. just need a little more help. the input txt file contains several 100 lines and i need to pick a particular line and assign. this integer/float inputs will be used for further calculations. maybe one method is to select the lines based on the line numbers and is there any possibility to identify a name (string) in the txt file and based on the string can we call from python?

Answer (score 0):

I think `Zone` is comma separated, which makes it a list -

```
Zone = [4001, 4002, 4003, 4004,...,4806]
```

Suppose your file is `filename.txt` -

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'r')
numbers = f.readlines()[-1].split() # assuming that it's the last line in text file
numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]
```

This will give you a list of zones as integers

Comment: there are several line in the txt file. need to select the input either by line number or need to check the any other possibility to call any string or name..

Comment: this will be good, if we good able to bring all the lines in the txt file..

Comment: If you could provide more data from text file, it'd be easier to see if there's a pattern

Comment: the tx file in the below formate, i can change this formate also, tha ts not an issue, totally 30 lines now  "line1: zone 
Line1:4001 4002 4003 4004 4005 4006 4007 4011 4012 4014
Line3: fro 
Line4:1 3 3 4 5 7 8 8 8 9
line5: to 
Line6: 6 3 1 2 1 1 4 10 12 22
Line7:PG 
line8:0 0 0 1519.1 0 0 0 0 0 0
Line9: PL 
Line10: 577.5 766.2 725.4 286 296.6 104 49.2 616 312.8 480.9 etc..
 "  here i given only 10 values for simplification, but actual the values will be more than 500. Is that is possible to call this values as a matrix and then each column/ row to be assigned to ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict` type to identify a name and retrieve its value.
Suppose your data file is `filename.txt` with

```
Zone
4001 4002 4003 4004
Tom
123.2 133.4
```

You can write the following Python code to access the data:

```
dict = {}
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        string_list = next(f).split()
        dict[i.strip()] = [float(j) for j in string_list]

print(dict)
```